# Where to safely store ssh private key?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using ssh keys to log in some servers. My private keys hasn't a passphrase, but I'd like to store it in an encrypted online storage service. Is that safe? Are there any free available options?
If I decided to add a passphrase to my key, could I safely store it in services such as Google Drive?

Is there a way to use the same key both with and without passphrase or should I make two different? In that way, I could use the first on my personal laptop and store the latter on GDrive.

Comment: 1) if you think an encrypted online service is more secure than adding a passphrase to the key and storing it locally, you're trusting the cloud admins more than yourself; that's not sensible.  2) if you want to look into ways of securely storing a local key, consider using a smart card (examples include [the FSFE Fellowship Smart Card](https://fsfe.org/fellowship/card.en.html)).

Comment: I don't need it to be more secure, just believe that it might be quicker to log in servers if I had not to digit the passphrase every single time.

Comment: That's what `ssh-agent` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protect your SSH key with a passphrase and use an SSH Agent so that you only have to type the passphrase when loading the key to the agent. See [man ssh-agent](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-agent.1), [ssh-agent on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) and [Using Pageant](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant)

Comment: I think I'll go with adding a passphrase and using pageant on my laptop

Answer (score 1):

What I personally do is store it in a Keepass database that has a password and use the KeeAgent plugin for Keepass. I also sync Keepass with S3 using a plugin.